# fancyBox - do I have to use title?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I've got a fancyBox light box working on my page, however I am not sure how to get a caption to appear.

HTML:

```
<a href="LINK TO IMAGE" target="_blank" class="fancybox"><div class="image">
<img src="img/small/06-small.jpg"> <h2>CAPTION TEXT<h2></div></a>
```

The documentation all uses examples where the a href link has a title tag, and it's this tag that is uses to show the caption string, but can I somehow get it to take the string from my h2 elements instead?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with the `title` option

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  title:$(this).find('h2').text()
});
```

[jsfiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/mica/7836wpnb/2/)

*PS : I also clean your code in this fiddle*

Comment: Excellent, thank you - that works. Now I just need to work out how to only display the caption from the photo clicked on, because at present it's showing everything in one long string. Maybe because I am building up the photo elements via a JS array?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. 
Can you describe the issue ? (maybe you already fix it)
And it will be nice if you vote for my answer